# copy files to another directory AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am QA'ing a feature using Protractor that requires changing a file on the branch (env.js file). I need to change 'GET' to 'POST' and then run my test. Then change this back to 'GET' once the test is completed.

```
 ==Path to file that needs to change > /app/scripts/env.js==   
 window.__env.postMethod = 'GET';
```

I was thinking that I could make two copies of the env.js file. One with the changes and the original file. When the test runs, I just copy the env.js file (/test/pages/support/modified_env.js) with the change overwriting the original file(/app/scripts/env.js). And when the test concludes, I then copy the original file back. 
My problem is I am not sure how to copy files to a different directory with Angularjs since I am relatively new to it. Suggestions? Are there any other options to changing this from 'GET' to 'POST' without modifying the file?

```
 ==sudo code (sorry I only know linux copy commands)==
 cp /test/pages/support/modified_env.js /app/scripts/env.js
 //run my tests
 cp /test/pages/support/original_env.js /app/scripts/env.js
```

My other concern is this test will also run on CI (Jenkins and Github). Would this be of concern copying files around during CI tests?

Answer (score 2):

Protractor is run on Node.js which means you have to write the file copying in JavaScript.

In Protractor [configuration](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts), you can provide function to prepare and clean up your tests with `onPrepare()` and `onCleanUp()`. In those functions, you could use Node.js' file system module to copy files. Below is an example.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('source-file').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('target-file'));
```

Comment: Hi @DennisFerguson, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.There is no obligation to do this.